# CSS class not getting added to the LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, dynamic, lwc-dom, shadow-dom

I Have created an LWC component with following files

> .HTML file

```
...
<lightning-datatable
  key-field="id"
  data={data}
  columns={columnsInProgress}
  is-loading={tableLoadingState}
  hide-checkbox-column=true>
</lightning-datatable>
...
```

> .js file

```
...
const columnsInProgress = [
        { label: 'Opportunity', fieldName: 'OpportunityName', fieldName: 'oppUrl', type: 'url',
            typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'OpportunityName' }, target: '_self'},
        },
        { label: 'Type', fieldName: 'OpportunityType', 
            cellAttributes: {class : {fieldName:'oppTypeClass'}}
        },
        { label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'OpportunityStage' },
        { label: 'Next Step', fieldName: 'OpportunityNextStep' }
    ];

...
```

assignment

```
...
if(row.lkpOpportunityActive__r.RecordType){
   rowData.oppTypeClass = row.lkpOpportunityActive__r.RecordType.Name == 'Retention'?'fontRed':'';
}
...
```

> .css

```
td.fontRed {
    color: red;
}
```

Now the cell is getting the CSS class applied but the text is not changing RED because the CSS file is not getting applied somehow. How can we control and apply the CSS dynamically?

> OUTPUT

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, only standard SLDS classes work with `cellAttributes`, but you are fortunate that we have a standard class to make text red. Use `slds-text-color_destructive` to get the red font color.

Comment: Wooh... You saved me from the all difficult alternatives from redesigning the component. Yes, fortunate that I just need the red color. :) Thank You, Rahul! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this something new? I can find this in documentation? check the photo I shared in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the documentation that this seems to be possible. Can anyone highlight why it was not working for me or now it is possible?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation

[image]

Comment: It has been there from the beginning but didn't work, might be possible that it started working lately. Did you try it?

Comment: No, I was working on another similar thing and noticed this and tried again but still, it was not working.